# morphism on varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to prove that: Let $X$ be an affine variety in $\mathbf{A}^n_k$ and $f\in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ such that $f: X\longrightarrow k$ is not a constant function, then $f$ is surjective? Or, weakly, $k\backslash f(X)$ is finite?

Comment: In your definition, an affine variety is irreducible?

Comment: Yes. Maybe it's also true in general for quasi-affine.

Comment: For quasi-affines, it is of course false by definition...

Answer (score 1):

This statement appears to be false. Let $X=\{xy=1\} \subset \mathbf A^2$, and let $f=x$.

Comment: Actually, I want to know whether $k\backslash f(X)$ is finite or not?